# How to move the properties and relationships of one node to another?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two separate nodes in the graph, and at one point I will get a signal that those two nodes should actually be one. So I have to merge the two including their properties (there's no overlap) AND I should maintain the relationships as well.

Example graph: `(d)->(a {id:1}), (b)->(c {name:"Sam"})`

Desired result: `(d)->(a {id:1, name:"Sam"}), (b)->(a {id:1, name:"Sam"})`

The label `a` doesn't have to be the case really in the result - the point is we will have only one node representing the original two.

The following merges the properties fine.

```
MATCH (a:Entity {id:"1"}), (c:Entity {name:"Sam"})
SET a += c
```

But I can't seem to find a way to move/copy the relationships.

The specs:

- The two nodes won't have the same properties
- node `a` *may* have incoming and outgoing relationships
- node `c` *may* have incoming relationships, non outgoing

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

The following works, assuming the type and properties coming to node `c` are known in advance. Can I improve this to make it more dynamic?

```
MATCH (a:Entity {id1:"1"}), (c:Entity {id2:"2"})
SET a += c
WITH a, c
MATCH (c)<-[r]-(b)
WITH a, c, r, b
MERGE (b)-[:REL_NAME {prop1:r.prop1, prop2:r.prop2}]->(a)
WITH c
DETACH DELETE c
```

**Update 2:**
The above throws `unable to load relationship with id` error sometimes and I'm not sure why, but it seems it's related to reading/writing at the same time.

**Update 3:**
This is a work around for the error:

```
MATCH (a:Entity {id1:"1"}), (c:Entity {id2:"2"})
SET a += c
WITH a, c
MATCH (c)<-[r]-(b)
WITH a, c, r, b
MERGE (b)-[r2:REL_NAME]->(a)
SET r2 += r
WITH r, c
DELETE r, c
```

Comment: This might work MERGE (b)-[r2:REL_NAME]->(a) set r2 = r

Comment: Cheers @Evgen that's much better.

Comment: What does a += c and r2 += r in the query in Update 3 mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem when moving relationships between nodes is that you can't set the relationship type dynamically.

So you can't `MATCH` all relationships from node `c` and recreate them on node `a`. This does **not** work:

```
MATCH (a:Entity {id1:"1"}), (c:Entity {id2:"2"})
WITH a, c
// get rels from node c
MATCH (c)-[r]-(b)
WITH a, c, r, b
// create the same rel from node a
MERGE (b)-["r.rel_type" {prop1:r.prop1, prop2:r.prop2}]->(a)
```

With neo4j 3 there are so called procedures which are plugins for the server and can be called from Cypher queries. The `apoc` procedure package provides procedures that do what you need: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/

First install the apoc plugin on your server, then use something like:

```
// create relationships with dynamic types
CALL apoc.create.relationship(person1,'KNOWS',{key:value,…​}, person2)

// merge nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([node1,node2])
```

Comment: That's very good to know - thanks Martin! Unfortunately I'm working with < 3.0. So is creating the relationship type dynamically impossible with neo4j < 3.0?

Comment: I think it's not possible with a Cypher query in neo4j < 3.0.